# ImportError: No module named pg8000

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I use aws-glue now and would like to connect aws-glue to aws-aurora(Postgres)!

So, I created aws-glew job to connect aws-glue to aws-aurora(Postgres) by using pg8000.

But I get the error message like title:

> ImportError: No module named pg8000
>
> No module named pg8000

When creating job, I set parameter of python library through S3.

How can I solve this problem? And how can I connect aws-glue to aws-aurora(Postgres)?

Answer (score 1):

You can import the library by installing it using easy_install as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852126/4326922

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can connect to Aurora Postgres only through an Amazon RDS instance. See supported connections [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html)

Comment: Comment thanks !!!
I can connect to Aurora Postgres by using Glue GUI. 
Next would like to connect to Aurora Postgres by using PyShell !!