# How can i crawl well the csv file inclued struct type data by using AWS-Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Thank you so much!

I can solve this problem ([ImportError: No module named pg8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608808/importerror-no-module-named-pg8000/55682904#55682904))

I encounter another problems.....

I use AWS-Glue to crawl some datas.
Most of data I can crawl.

But one data I can not crawl

one data's column has this struct
{"covercd":"$$$$$","covernm":"$$$$","covertype":"$","insuredamt":"1####","displayflg":"###","displayname":"****","displayorder":"####"}

after crawling this data is 
{covercd={"covercd":"$$$$$","covernm":"$$$$$","covertype":"$$$$$","insuredamt":"$$$$$","displayflg":"$$$$$","displayname":"$$$$$","displayorder":"$$$$$"}, covernm=null, covertype=null, insuredamt=null, displayflg=null, displayname=null, displayorder=null, insurefee=null}

why is the data's column this??

I don't understand the reason....

Pelease help me !!!!