# Python Boto3 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'iter_lines'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue, botocore

I am using Boto3 to read the results of my Athena query in a python script.

I have the following code that works fine in AWS Lambda.

```
def get_athena_results(s3_bucket, s3_output_path, execution_id):
    s3client = boto3.client('s3')
    key = s3_output_path + '/' + execution_id + '.csv'
    obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=key)
    results_iterator = obj['Body'].iter_lines()
    results = [r for r in results_iterator]
    return results
```

When I run the same function in AWS Glue **Python Shell** (Not a Spark job), I get the error:

```
Unexpected error: <class 'AttributeError'>
'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'iter_lines'
```

This doesn't make sense to me as the `botocore.response.StreamingBody` class has an `iter_lines` method, and it works fine in AWS Lambda.

https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html

Any idea why this is happening in AWS Glue Python Shell?

Thanks

Comment: Check the version of boto3 package in Glue

Comment: This issue seems to be happening because of version mismatch. Can you print versions in your Glue job,Lambda function and compare ?   print("boto3 version:"+boto3.__version__)
print("botocore version:"+botocore.__version__)

Comment: Hi, I used your code @bdcloud and I am seeing `boto3 version:1.9.130`. It seems like Glue's Boto is not the last available.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972342/update-boto3-for-aws-glue

I tried updating it using subprocesses but run with user permission issues. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @DiegoSerrano Can you try installing the version which is matching lambda in your Glue python shell. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852126/4326922 and mention package as boto3==1.9.130(version from lambda) and let me know how it goes

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion provided? Did it helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happened as, at the time posting the question, Glue's Boto3 is on a previous version VS the one available in lambda, where `iter_lines()` is unavailable.