# Python List Comprehension from S3 file read with boto3 in AWS Glue Python Shell Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

I can do this easily using the smart_open package:

```
from smart_open import open

for line in open('s3://mybucket/myfolder/myfile.csv'):
   print(line)
```

How to do the same using boto3?

P.S. I need to do this in a Python Shell Job in AWS Glue, without having to package smart_open and set it up as a "Python library path" in the Glue Job.

Comment: can you try it installing through easy install as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852126/4326922 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please provide a clear good working example? Use the smart_open package as an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618468/read-a-file-line-by-line-from-s3-using-boto