# How to write a pandas dataframe to AWS Athena table using python script

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am having dataframe like below

```
Rate.head(4)

 KG  Europe_Rate  NAP_Rate
 1     10          8
 2     16          12
 3     19          16
 4     22          18
```

I want insert this data into AWS table. How can this be done?

```
Database: Rate
Table   :Customer_Rate
```

The columns types in AWS athena is double ( KG, Europe_Rate, NAP_Rate).

Comment: I am also looking for the answer

Comment: I was researching about this. `import awswrangler as wr` doesnt work`. Somebody please post an answer

Comment: @RiaAlves, You correct, ` awswrangler doesnt work' it  gives cannot import name 'infer_compression' error. I am also having an similar issue. looking for an solution

Comment: Can you confirm where you are running import awswrangler as wr statement in? Which environment ?

Comment: @bdcloud, I am running `import awswrangler as wr` in a sagemaker jupyter notebook and my anacond version is `3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0]`

Comment: Can you try installing it in your code using easy install and see if its working fine ? refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852126/4326922

Comment: @bdcloud, I am also having same issue while importing awswrangler. Can you explain little bit more . I referred the question you have shared but not able connect. If you post as answer will be good

Comment: Try installing it with below code :.                      import os import site from setuptools.command import easy_install install_path = os.environ['GLUE_INSTALLATION'] easy_install.main( ["--install-dir", install_path, "<library-name>"] ) reload(site) import <installed library>

Answer (score 1):

AWS Athena queries data on S3. It supports many different types of data such as CSV, JSON, Parquet, etc. If you write your data frame as a CSV to an S3 bucket and then create a table in Athena you will be able to query the data with Athena. You can find an example of how to create a table that reads CSV data here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html