# Can't install pyarrow on AWS Glue python shell

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-glue, pyarrow

I want to import `pyarrow` in a Python shell Glue script because I need to export a dataframe as parquet (i.e. with `DataFrame.to_parquet()`).

The way to add custom dependencies suggested in the AWS docs is to use `.egg` or `.whl` files (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#create-python-extra-library).

The library `pyarrow` has `numpy` and `six` as dependencies:

- `numpy` is already pre-installed on Glue, with version `1.16.2` as I checked with a simple `print(numpy.version.version)`
- `six` is not pre-installed so I downloaded `six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` from Pypi and uploaded it to S3.
- `pyarrow` is not pre-installed so I downloaded from Pypi the wheel file `pyarrow-0.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` and uploaded it to S3.

The script itself is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import six
import numpy
from pyarrow import *

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'],dtype=float)
df.to_parquet('test.parquet')
```

When I run the script adding as libraries the wheel files of `six` and `pyarrow`, I get the following message:

```
Processing ./glue-python-libs-f8nyy9el/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.14.0
Processing ./glue-python-libs-f8nyy9el/pyarrow-0.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

and the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7d78c96e10>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7d78c96c88>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7d78c96dd8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7d78c969b0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7d78c96898>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>=1.14 (from pyarrow==0.16.0) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy>=1.14 (from pyarrow==0.16.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 112, in <module>
    download_and_install(args.extra_py_files)
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 62, in download_and_install
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--target=
{}
".format(install_path), local_file_path])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/glue/lib/installation', '/tmp/glue-python-libs-f8nyy9el/pyarrow-0.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

So at first, it seems that six is installed correctly, but then it looks like the job does not realize that `numpy` is already present with a compatible version.

Then I tried to upload to S3 also the wheel file `s3://risultati-navigazione-wt-ga/libs/numpy-1.18.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` that I downloaded from Pypi. In this case I get the message:

```
Processing ./glue-python-libs-xzfdvgzd/numpy-1.18.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.2
Processing ./glue-python-libs-xzfdvgzd/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.14.0
Processing ./glue-python-libs-xzfdvgzd/pyarrow-0.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

and the error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fca02861cc0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fca02861cc0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fca02861cc0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fca02861cc0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fca02861cc0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement six>=1.0.0 (from pyarrow==0.16.0) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for six>=1.0.0 (from pyarrow==0.16.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 112, in <module>
    download_and_install(args.extra_py_files)
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 62, in download_and_install
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--target=
{}
".format(install_path), local_file_path])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/glue/lib/installation', '/tmp/glue-python-libs-xzfdvgzd/pyarrow-0.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

so, this time, `numpy` is recognized during the installation of pyarrow but, as far I understand, although`six` is installed correctly, for some reason pyarrow can't find it during the installation and indeed it tries to download from the Internet (it gets stuck a few minutes during that operation).

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: try installing it as mentioned in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852126/4326922

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I uploaded this linux version of `pyarrow` to S3 and it's path to the Python library path box in the edit job modal:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/57/f9a96302f27f0008f5afcd4232d4df66a6af5e568445128cac52f64ee4fd/pyarrow-3.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl

You could use easy-install like Mauro's answer above^ but I believe that will be deprecated sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

To use `pyarrow` it is neccessary to build your own package. In `setup.py` you have to specify `pyarrow` as one of `install_requires`.

```
setup(
    name="PACKAGE_NAME",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'pyarrow'
    ],
)
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#create-python-extra-library) you find more information about building a package for AWS glue.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#python-shell-supported-library) also `pandas` should be added in this way.

> pandas (required to be installed via the python setuptools configuration, setup.py)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
This is not valid anymore and libs must be added with the WHL.

---

Previous answare:
Try to add:

```
import os
import site
import importlib
from setuptools.command import easy_install
install_path = os.environ['GLUE_INSTALLATION']

libraries = ["pyarrow"]
for lib in libraries:
    easy_install.main( ["--install-dir", install_path, lib] )

importlib.reload(site)
```

at the beginning of the Glue Python Shell code. This seems to work better than adding .whl libs in the Python library path.

Comment: This snippet totally works still, I just used it.