# Using AWS X-Ray within a Glue Python Shell Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, aws-xray

**Is it possible to use [x-ray patching for boto3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-python-patching.html) within a Glue python shell job using the standard deployed environment?**

The [`aws-xray-sdk`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-python.html) library is not in the [list of supported libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html).  But not including the ability to instrument `boto3`, which is in the supported library list, would seem like a glaring omission.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Have you tried using easy install inside your python shell job and pass aws-xray-sdk as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852126/4326922 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the easy install method suggested by Prabhakar to include the aws-xray-sdk in your glue job. But the SDK needs the [X-Ray Daemon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon.html) to send data to the AWS X-Ray service. You'll need to spin up the daemon and have its host and port open to receive segments from your glue job. You'll also need to set the `AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS` env var to the daemon's address.