# aws x-ray with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

This is my Python code with AWS X-Ray

There is no Error  but it is not sending anything to X-Ray Daemon.

What is missing in this code ?

````
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder


xray_recorder.configure(daemon_address="xx.xx.xx.xx:2000")
# Start a segment
segment = xray_recorder.begin_segment('segment_name')
# Start a subsegment
subsegment = xray_recorder.begin_subsegment('subsegment_name')

# Add metadata and annotations
segment.put_metadata('key', dict, 'namespace')
subsegment.put_annotation('key', 'value')

# Close the subsegment and segment
xray_recorder.end_subsegment()
xray_recorder.end_segment()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the prerequisites in place to use x-ray? This means:

1. Make sure the lambda has permissions to send to x-ray. Lambda needs the following permissions to send trace data to X-Ray. Add them to your function's execution role.

   - xray:PutTraceSegments
   - xray:PutTelemetryRecords

These permissions are included in the `AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess` managed policy.

2. Recommended: enable active tracing on your lambda. This sends data to x-ray out of the box and enables some useful troubleshooting capabilities like lambda cold start times.

More info [in the aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html#services-xray-permissions)

Comment: I am not using Lambda. I'm using this code in AWS Glue Job that is written in Python . There is no issue with permission either since I am using full xray:* permission.  What is the possible cause that it is not writing to X-Ray ? Is there any code missing here ?

Comment: Have you seen this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594081/using-aws-x-ray-within-a-glue-python-shell-job? Does it help in any way?

Comment: yes. I have seen that post. I already have AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS  in the code and also in VM env variable and  added x-ray SDK library in Glue and a VM spinned up to listen on 2000 port.  My only hunch is , is my above Python code correct ? Is there anything I am missing ?  do I require some code like  xray_recorder.send()  .....something like this ? // there is no send anyway,  but you get the idea,

Comment: To debug, you can add `import logging` to the top and add `logging.getLogger('aws_xray_sdk').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` right after importing the x ray sdk. Maybe the logs help you further